# Is there a way to manually add tags using dictionaries for named entity recognision?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am a beginner and I want to know if there is a way to/How can I manually add tags using dictionaries for named entity recognition. I am using spacy for Named Entity Recognition and when I used the below code  :

```
import spacy 
from spacy import display
raw_text='''To determine the adulticidal and repellent activities of different solvent leafextracts of Rhinacanthus nasutus against Aedes aegypti and Culex quinquefasciatus.'''  
NER = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") 
text1= NER(raw_text) 
for word in text1.ents:
    print(word.text,word.label_)
```

it gave this as output:
Rhinacanthus NORP
Aedes ORG

but i want the word Aedes to be tagged as a person not ORG. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [rule based matching tutorial](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching/) in the spaCy docs. If there is a word you know should always be a particular entity type you can use the EntityRuler to match it, something like this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")
patterns = [{"label": "PERSON", "pattern": "Aedes"}]
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
```